# Rearrange Spaces via command line from the terminal emulator

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, spaces, mission-control

**TL;DR:** I need to replace the dashboard with a terminal emulator.

Hi.

I need to 'rearrange spaces' so a terminal emulator gets first from the left before the desktop, where the dashboard used to be. I thought of making an Automator app which would launch iTerm2, put it in fullscreen mode and put its space to the leftmost, but I can't even get the terminal to enter full screen. I tried all I know to do with `defaults-write`. Months ago, I scratched an AppleScript that failed, which I don't find anymore. I searched for a way to force-reorder and refresh Spaces so the terminal is placed first. I also looked if Spaces can be hacked to reserve a given space for a given app. I found nothing.

What -- I think -- must be done:

1. ***OK*** Disable Dashboard.
2. ***OK*** Set Mission Control not to work like Exposé.
3. ***OK*** Launch say iTerm2 at login.

   1. ***KO*** Automatically make it enter full screen.
   2. ***KO*** Reorder the spaces to place it first leftmost, before the Desktop.
4. ***KO*** If done in foreground, go back to Desktop.

What I did so far:

- First, I disabled Dashboard by entering `defaults write com.apple.dock dashboard-in-overlay -bool TRUE && defaults write com.apple.dock mru-spaces -bool FALSE`.

  - Also, I disabled spaces autoreordering with `defaults write com.apple.dock mru-spaces -bool FALSE`.
- Second, I set Mission Control's behavior as Mission Control's, not as Exposé's with `defaults write com.apple.dock expose-group-by-app -bool FALSE`.

Now, I need a way to launch a terminal in fullscreen mode or quickly make it enter full screen. After that, I will have to place it first.

Whatever working solution will be fine, whether using AppleScript or whatever else, whether happening in background or in foreground, be it kludging a dirty hack or a smooth Apple-compliant way. If I could, I would rather have it running silently in the background while being made out of as few different Apple technology as possible. I am on OS X Mavericks, OS X Yosemite and macOS High Sierra.

Thank you.

Have a nice day.